# React / CARTO Enabling interactions

Tags: javascript, carto, carto-js, react

I have a React JS component that adds a Layer to the Basemap:

```
 componentDidMount() {
    const { client } = this.props;

    // Craete source, styles and layer with the given props
    const cartoSource = new carto.source.Dataset("dataset");
    const cartoCSS = new carto.style.CartoCSS(style);
    const layer = new carto.layer.Layer(cartoSource, cartoCSS, {
      featureClickColumns: [
        "geoid2"
      ]
    });

    // Add them to the client and to the map
    client.addLayer(layer);
    client.getLeafletLayer().addTo(this.context.map);
```

I would like to display the geoID when I hover over the polygon, and also highlight it. Having a hard time understanding how this could be done in React.

Comment: Have you checked the example on adding interactivity from the Developer Center? https://carto.com/developers/carto-js/examples/#example-detect-feature-over-out

Answer (score 0):

In that same method you can add a handler for the `featureOver` event.

`layer.on('featureOver', featureEvent => {
  // featureEvent.data.geoid2 has the value
});`

Then you can do whatever you need with that value. In your case you want to display a popup with the value. You can use the popup that comes from Leaflet if you're using Leaflet as the provider.

https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.2.html#popup

Where you manage the popup it's up to you and your app structure.

What you can't do is highlight the polygon. This would need a server request to receive new tiles. If you need that kind of visual feedback, take a look on CARTO VL, our vector library. There's an example that's just what you want. https://carto.com/developers/carto-vl/examples/#example-interactive-based-styling